# Best way to get and store data (optimized) to mobile app (Ionic, Cordova/Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to do an app with ionic framework and cordova for Android and iOs and I want to optimize at most the requests to the server.

I need to get data from php server (API) and store in the mobile phone, this data is related, so I think that a SQLite is the best option to store it in the device because of to show it is more fast to do a complex SQL than get a JSON stored in localstorage (for example) and search and link the data in the mobile. I'm right?

I need to do this and can do a Pull to refresh in the app and get only new data.

I've been watching some solutions but I don't know what is the best.

Parse/Firebase: This is difficult to administrate for non-specialists, for this I have a backend to enter and modify data with the relations easily. In addition this services return a JSON with more data that I need.

Persistence.js and Persistence.sync.js this works with mysql-server and sqlite-local but can I sync only one table or get only the new data? And I did't find a solution for php server.

CouchDB and PouchDB: I don't know if this can be sync only for a new records.

Receive data in JSON and store it in SQLite: I need to create functions to do this easier.

Any other solutions?

I'm very lost in this topic.

Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like this would be a good post for the ionic forum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CouchDB and PouchDB: I don't know if this can be sync only for a new records.

That’s the default. Plus they handle all the nasty sync details for you. Would highly recommend looking into this.